# SortedList lança exceção System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#

Eu estou tentando implementar um código para achar o melhor caminho em um grafo. Consegui desenvolver o método com recursão e agora estou tentando implementar usando pilha.

O problema é que eu recebo exceção quando tento acessar .Min(), e isso não acontece com a recursão.

O resto do código está funcionando.

Se tiver outras sugestões, também agradeço

Aqui está o código da recursão e da pilha

```
public KeyValuePair<int, List<GrafoNode>> AcharCaminho_recursao(GrafoNode inicio, GrafoNode fim)
{
    var visitados = new List<GrafoNode>();
    visitados.Add(fim);
    return AcharCaminho_recursao(inicio, fim, visitados);
}

protected KeyValuePair<int, List<GrafoNode>> AcharCaminho_recursao(GrafoNode inicio, GrafoNode fim, List<GrafoNode> visitados)
{
    var caminho = new List<GrafoNode>();
    var caminhos = new SortedList<int, List<GrafoNode>>(); // caminhos possiveis

    if (ReferenceEquals(fim, inicio)) // isso VAI ACONTECER por causa da recursão
    {
        caminho.Add(inicio);
        return new KeyValuePair<int, List<GrafoNode>>(0, caminho);
    }

    foreach (var item in fim.Vizinhos)
    {
        if (!visitados.Contains(item)) // não pode voltar onde já foi
        {
            var node = (GrafoNode)item;
            visitados.Add(node);

            var pair = AcharCaminho_recursao(inicio, node, visitados); // RECURSÃO!!!

            if (!pair.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<int, List<GrafoNode>>)))
            // se o retorno da recursão não for "vazio"
            {
                pair.Value.Add(fim);
                var dist = pair.Key + fim.Custos[node];

                caminhos.Add(dist, pair.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    if (caminhos.Count > 0)
        return caminhos.Min(); // seleciona o menor caminho dos selecionados

    else
        return default(KeyValuePair<int, List<GrafoNode>>);
}

public KeyValuePair<int, List<GrafoNode>> AcharCaminho_pilha(GrafoNode inicio, GrafoNode fim)
{
    var caminhos = new SortedList<int, List<GrafoNode>>(); 
    var visitados = new List<GrafoNode>();

    var pilha = new Stack<GrafoNode>();
    var custo = 0;

    pilha.Push(fim);

    while (pilha.Count >= 1)
    {
        var retiraPilha = true;

        foreach (var item in pilha.Peek().Vizinhos)
        {
            if (!visitados.Contains(item))
            {
                var node = (GrafoNode)item;
                visitados.Add(node);
                custo += pilha.Peek().Custos[node];
                pilha.Push(node);

                if (item.Vizinhos.Contains(inicio))
                {
                    pilha.Push(inicio);
                    custo += node.Custos[inicio];

                    var lista = pilha.ToList();
                    caminhos.Add(custo, lista);

                    pilha.Pop();
                }

                else
                    retiraPilha = false;


                break;
            }
        }


        if (retiraPilha)
            pilha.Pop();
    }

    if (caminhos.Count > 0)
        return caminhos.Min(); // seleciona o menor caminho dos selecionados; A EXCEÇÃO É LANÇADA AQUI

    else
        return default(KeyValuePair<int, List<GrafoNode>>);
}
```

Detalhes da exceção:

> {"Pelo menos um objeto deve implementar IComparable."}

Se necessário, posso prover mais detalhes da implementação da classe GrafoPonderado.

Grato!

---

### Edit

[image: Print do erro]

Comment: Pode passar os detalhes da exceção e o stack trace?

Comment: Coloque dentro de um `try   {  } catch (Exception e){ } ` para pegar o que esta gerando o erro.

Comment: @DotNet é exatamente o oposto que se deve fazer

Comment: @bigown, não entendi muito bem o oposto. tira do try { } catch ?

Comment: Não deve colocar isto. Isto só vai esconder a exceção (que é o que o pessoa gosta de fazer, pq ninguém quer consertar nada, só fazer de conta q ñ tem erro), do jeito que está agora o erro é apresentado, é bem melhor. é só ele nos falar onde é.

Comment: Lembrem-se, que a linha que está dando erro é idêntica (aparentemente) ao método da recursão (que funciona)

Comment: @bigown  minha intenção era de ele  debugar e postar o erro que está gerando.

Comment: @Dot Net, já fiz uma edição na pergunta com a mensagem da exceção

Comment: @TiagoDall'Oca No título você passa um erro (que é diferente do que havia sido postado originalmente), depois diz que a exceção é outra. Não dá para confiar nestas informações. melhor postar o *stacktrace* completo, talvez até complementarmente um *print* do erro.

Comment: @DotNet se fizer a sua sugestão vai engolir o erro, melar tudo e dificultar a depuração

Comment: Seu GrafoNode implementar IComparable

Comment: @DotNet mas eu queria que a ordeação fosse feita através do `int`que eu passo: 
`caminhos.Add(custo, lista);`
Ou seja, a ordenação seria feita através do `int custo`. Isso parece funcionar na recursão